# How to make Form Visible in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, keyboard, panel

I am trying to design a piano for an assignment in C#. I have created a MusicKey class which stores music keys (as well as a BlackMusicKey class). I am populating the panel, 'panel1' with music keys like this:

```
this.panel1.Controls.Add(bmk);
```

In the music key constructor, I am setting a location and size for each music key, as well as ensuring that Visibility is set to true. However, when I run the form, it is completely blank.

Is there something that I am missing? I am quite sure that there is nothing wrong with the visibility of the music keys, so surely there is something that I am missing with regards to making the panel visible.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Note: I have also tried using `panel1.Show()` which still did not work.

All relevant code can be found down below:

MusicKeyClass:

```
class MusKey : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    private int musicNote; //determines the pitch mapped to number

    public MusKey(int iNote, int x, int y) : base()
    {
        musicNote = iNote;
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 80);
        this.Visible = true;

    }

    public int getMusicNote()
    {
        return musicNote;
    }
}
```

Form1 Class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int count = 0;
    int xLoc = 50;
    int yLoc = 30;
    int[] whitePitch = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24 };
    Panel panel1 = new Panel();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    Button button1 = new Button();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(function);
        MusKey mk;
        BlackMusKey bmk;
        for (int k = 0; k < 14; k++)
        {
            int pitch = whitePitch[k];
            int ixPos = k * 20;
            mk = new MusKey(pitch, ixPos, yLoc);
            mk.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseDown);
            mk.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseUp); 
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(mk);
        }


        int xOffs = 20;
        int[] blackPitch = { 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 19, 21, 23 };
        int[] xPos = { 10, 30, 70, 110, 150, 170, 210, 230, 250 };
        const int yPosBlack = 50;

        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            int pitch = blackPitch[k];
            int ixPos = xPos[k];
            bmk = new BlackMusKey(pitch, ixPos, yPosBlack);
            bmk.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseDown); //create event MouseDown
            bmk.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseUp);  //create event MouseUp
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(bmk);
            this.panel1.Controls[this.panel1.Controls.Count - 1].BringToFront();
        }


    }

    SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
    int count1;

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MusKey mk in this.panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (sender == mk)
            { //true for the specific key pressed on the Music Keyboard
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = true; //variable of the Timer component
                    count = 0; //incremented by the timer1_Tick event handler
                    timer1.Start();
                    sp.SoundLocation = (mk.getMusicNote() + ".wav"); //might need to convert ToString() ??
                    sp.Play();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = count++;
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MusKey mk in this.panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (sender == mk) //true for the specific key pressed on the Music Keyboard
            {
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    sp.Stop();
                    string bNoteShape = null;
                    int duration = 0;
                    if (count >= 16)
                    {
                        bNoteShape = "SemiBreve";
                        duration = 16;
                    }
                    if (count >= 8 && count <= 15)
                    {
                        bNoteShape = "DotMinim";
                        duration = (8 + 15) / 2;
                    }
                    if (count >= 4 && count <= 7)
                    {
                        bNoteShape = "Crotchet";
                        duration = (4 + 7) / 2;
                    }
                    if (count >= 2 && count <= 3)
                    {
                        bNoteShape = "Quaver";
                        duration = (2 + 3) / 2;
                    }
                    if (count >= 1)
                    {
                        bNoteShape = "Semi-Quaver";
                        duration = 1;
                    }
                    MusicNote mn = new MusicNote(mk.getMusicNote(), duration, bNoteShape); //music note construction
                                                                                           // mn.Location = new Point(xLoc, yLoc);
                                                                                           //this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.mn); //adding MusicNote component to MusicStaff (panel2) collection
                    xLoc = xLoc + 15;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void function(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Show();
        panel1.Visible = true;
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        panel1.Size = new Size(5, 5);
        panel1.Location = new Point(3, 3);
        this.Controls.Add(panel1);
        this.Controls.Add(button1);

    }

    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Form 1 [designer] Class:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    // <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load_1);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Music Note Class

```
class MusicNote
{
    public int notepitch;
    public String noteshape;
    public int noteduration;
    enum accid { sharp, flat, sole };


    bool dragging = false;
    System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public MusicNote(int iNotepitch, int iDuration, String iBnoteShape)
    {
        notepitch = iNotepitch;
        noteduration = iDuration;
        noteshape = iBnoteShape;
    }

    bool timeron = false;
    bool changenote = false;
    public static int start = 0;


    //public void click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }

    //public void RightPress(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }

}
```

}

Black Music Key Class

```
 class BlackMusKey : MusKey
{
    public BlackMusKey(int iNote, int x, int y) : base(iNote, x, y)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 60);
    }
}
```

Program Class

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this ?  `panel1.Visible =true;`

Comment: Can you show the code that sets the position? Are you sure that the position is in the visible area of the parent panel? Which UI framework do you use? Can you also show the MusicKey class? Which class does it inherit from?

Comment: @Anas said what you must to do. If it doesn't work, please, post your code. Help us to help you.

Comment: @Anas I did as can be seen at the top of Form1_Load

Comment: @Markus relevant code has been uploaded. MusicKey inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Button.

Comment: @Sinatr I have just uploaded the relevant code.

Comment: *"relevant code"* - this is something, but still not enough. Your code is missing a lot of things: `yLoc`,  (maybe it's negative), `BlackMusKey`, actual form (maybe you have something wrong with layout). Consider preparing [mcve].

Comment: i think this may be problem with your `bmk` control - not with panel itself. please change your panel background and run application to verify if i'm right.

Comment: @MaciejS. i have tried changing background colour to blue (added it to code), however still nothing shows up. Could it be perhaps related to the fact that I must somewhere include the PaintEventHandler?

Comment: @Luke Xuereb - i don't think so that it's related to any event. how do you create your panel? via designer or in code?

Comment: @MaciejS. created it in code.

Comment: please paste your panel-creating code to your question as well as code which add it to form. it may be very helpful.

Comment: @MaciejS. just uploaded all code to the question

Comment: Ok... If your `Form1` class is fully pasted here, so I see one BIG problem - you have deleted constructor! I have copied part of your code to blank VS form, and I see some problem with button and panel locations, but it's nothing hard to correct. Main problem is deleted constructor so `InitializeComponent()` method from designer class is never fired. Please add following code: `public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }` and you should see your panel and buttons. Please leave a comment if it works so I will write proper answer to this thread.

Comment: @MaciejS Yes, this was the issue. Working on fixing location and size will be small issues, but the constructor was indeed missing and so the form was not loading, not even the title. Thank you very much for your extremely helpful comment!

Comment: @Luke Xuereb glad to hear that. I added proper answer to this thread. Please accept it for help other people to find solutions for similiar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Form1 class code, there is constructor missing. Please add proper constructor with `InitializeComponent()` method call. It can be added anywhere in class body.
Code snippet:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [...] //your objects declarations

    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [...] //rest of your code
}
```